# Moveit dynamic limits on joints

Tags: moveit, planning, limits

In Moveit, How can I specify additional limits on joints as constraint. For example joint1-joint2 between 20deg to 90 deg.
I want Moveit to plan trajectory to respect these limits.
These limits is for robot with four bar linkage, which is modelled as open chain and now I want to enforce the limits.